# cannot import name '__pyarmor__' from 'hexlet_python_package.libruntime' (unknown location)

Tags: python, obfuscation, pyarmor

everything good?
I'm obfuscating the [hexlet_python_package](https://github.com/hexlet-boilerplates/python-package) project. A template package for python. However, when I try to import and use the library implementations, I get an error where libruntime is located.

To generate the code obfuscation I am using the [Building obfuscated wheel tutorial](https://pyarmor.readthedocs.io/en/stable/how-to/wheel.html#building-obfuscated-wheel).

my machine (Mac m1)  is configured with:

```
Python 3.11.7
Poetry (version 1.8.2)
Pyarmor 8.5.0 (trial), 000000, non-profits

License Type    : pyarmor-trial
License No.     : pyarmor-vax-000000
License To      : 
License Product : non-profits

BCC Mode        : No
RFT Mode        : No
```

my setup.cfg:

```
[flake8]
accept-encodings = utf-8
max-complexity = 6
statistics = False
max-line-length = 80
enable-extensions = G
isort-show-traceback = True

exclude = .git,__pycache__,.venv,dist,build

ignore =
  # line break occurred before a binary operator
  W503

per-file-ignores =
  # init modules can contain the local imports, logic, unused imports
  __init__.py: F401

[isort]
multi_line_output = 3
include_trailing_comma = true
default_section = FIRSTPARTY
line_length = 79

[metadata]
    name = hexlet_python_package
    version = attr: hexlet_python_package.VERSION

[options]
    package_dir =
        =dist/

    packages =
        hexlet_python_package
        hexlet_python_package.pyarmor_runtime_000000

    include_package_data = True
```

my pyproject.toml:

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "hexlet-python-package"
version = "0.3.0"
description = ""
authors = ["skip"]
readme = "README.md"

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = ">=3.8.1,<4.0"

[tool.poetry.group.dev.dependencies]
pytest = "^7.4.2"
pytest-cov = "^4.1.0"
flake8 = "^6.1.0"

[tool.poetry.scripts]
hexlet-python-package = "hexlet_python_package.scripts.hexlet_python_package:main"

[build-system]
requires = [
    "poetry-core>=1.0.0",
    "setuptools>=66.1.1",
    "wheel"
]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"
```

my MANIFEST.in:

```
recursive-include dist/hexlet_python_package/pyarmor_runtime_000000 *.so
recursive-include dist/hexlet_python_package/libruntime *.so
```

Error log when i try use into another project from pip install:

```
Ocorreu uma exceção: ImportError
cannot import name '__pyarmor__' from 'hexlet_python_package.libruntime' (unknown location)
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/babel-fish/python-sample-vscode-django-tutorial/feature/homeList/business/get_LogUseCase.py", line 2, in <module>
    from hexlet_python_package import user
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/babel-fish/python-sample-vscode-django-tutorial/hello/views.py", line 4, in <module>
    from feature.homeList.business.get_LogUseCase import GetLogUseCase
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/babel-fish/python-sample-vscode-django-tutorial/hello/urls.py", line 3, in <module>
    from hello import views
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/babel-fish/python-sample-vscode-django-tutorial/web_project/urls.py", line 22, in <module>
    path("", include("hello.urls")),
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/babel-fish/python-sample-vscode-django-tutorial/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/babel-fish/python-sample-vscode-django-tutorial/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
ImportError: cannot import name '__pyarmor__' from 'hexlet_python_package.libruntime' (unknown location)
```

```
tree : hexlet_python_package
├── __init__.py
├── __pycache__
│   ├── __init__.cpython-311.pyc
│   └── user.cpython-311.pyc
├── scripts
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── hexlet_python_package.py
└── user.py
```

```
tree: dist/hexlet_python_package
├── __init__.py
├── __pycache__
│   └── __init__.cpython-311.pyc
├── libruntime
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   └── __init__.cpython-311.pyc
│   └── pyarmor_runtime.so
├── pyarmor_runtime_000000
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── pyarmor_runtime.so
├── scripts
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── hexlet_python_package.py
└── user.py
```

Can anyone who has been through this help me? Thank you very much

Import and use a obfuscated library